# rails db:create succeeds, but then gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have a Rails app with a Dockerized PostgreSQL database. When I run `rails db` or `rails db:migrate`, it works perfectly fine.

When I run `rails db:create`, it behaves differently:

```
$ rails db:create                                                                                                     
Created database 'my_app_development'                                                                                                        
could not connect to server: No such file or directory                                                                                       
        Is the server running locally and accepting                                                                                          
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?                                                                              
Couldn't create 'my_app_test' database. Please check your configuration.                                                  
rails aborted!                                                                                                                               
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory                                               
        Is the server running locally and accepting                                                                                          
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?                                                                              
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'   
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'                              
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/spring:7:in `tap'                                                     
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'                                        
                                                                                                                                             
Caused by:                                                                                                                                   
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory                                                                    
        Is the server running locally and accepting                                                                                          
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?                                                                              
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'                                         
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'                              
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/spring:7:in `tap'                         
/Users/jasonswett/Documents/code/rails_application_template/my_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'                     
Tasks: TOP => db:create                                                                                                                      
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My suspicion is that for some reason `rails db:create` is trying to connect to my database on `127.0.0.1:5432` (which works) but then trying to connect to it again at `localhost:5432`, which will not work because `localhost` won't get to my container, only `127.0.0.1:5432` will.

Again, `rails db` and `rails db:migrate` work fine. When I try `rails db:create` and `rails db:drop`, I get the error above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. It's just that my test database settings were wrong (set to `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1`).